# Getting Errors I Don't Understand When Defining Templates Config for Tornado

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

UPDATE: I moved the MainHandler into the app.py file and removed the `from handlers import MainHandler` line and it works.  So apparently this has to do with my lack of understanding of how to pull in code from other files.

I'm new to Python which means I'm also new to Tornado.  I have what I think is the most simplest of Tornado apps.  When I was doing the following:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, World")
```

Things worked fine.  I've now modified my Application config to use templates. Here is my app.py:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import os.path

from handlers import MainHandler

application = tornado.web.Application(
    [
        (r"/", MainHandler)
    ],
    template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
    static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

And here is the MainHandler:

```
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html")
```

Here is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Index Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try and access `http://localhost:8888/` I am getting the following errors, which to me are pretty cryptic right now:

```
ERROR:tornado.application:Uncaught exception, closing connection.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 341, in wrapper
    callback(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 331, in wrapped
    raise_exc_info(exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 302, in wrapped
    ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 327, in _on_headers
    self.request_callback(self._request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1567, in __call__
    handler = spec.handler_class(self, request, **spec.kwargs)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback functools.partial(<function wrap.<locals>.wrapped at 0x104b78d40>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 458, in _run_callback
    callback()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 331, in wrapped
    raise_exc_info(exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 302, in wrapped
    ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 341, in wrapper
    callback(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 331, in wrapped
    raise_exc_info(exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 302, in wrapped
    ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 327, in _on_headers
    self.request_callback(self._request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1567, in __call__
    handler = spec.handler_class(self, request, **spec.kwargs)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: your code runs fine in my machine with Python 2.

Comment: So, what's in index.html?

Comment: @ColeMaclean I added that in my question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after much googling I have figured out my problem.

First, I had to add `__init__.py` to the handlers folder so that python recognized this as a package.  That seems pretty arbitrary so I'll have to read up on the logic of that later.

Secondly, I have to modify the import to `from handlers.MainHandler import *`, even thought what I ideally want to do is `from handlers import *` so that I can just import all my handlers at once.  For now, I'll settle with what is working.

Comment: In Python, the filename of a module is part of its fully-qualified name, so if you put your MainHandler class in a file of the same name the class is handlers.MainHandler.MainHandler.  `from X import *` will not automatically look for all available files; you must import them individually.  If you put `import MainHandler` (and so on for all your other handlers) in `__init__.py` it will work the way you expect.

Comment: Well, from some of the other reading I'm doing their saying it is best practice to do absolute imports and not * imports.  Which is fine. Coming from the Java world, the practice is the same.  So I'll probably modify to that.  But your explanation is helpful so thanks.

Comment: Another shortcut:  for the particular case of defining handlers, you can use (fully qualified) names without importing anything: `(r'/', 'handlers.MainHandler.MainHandler')`.  The Application will import these classes automatically.